# Cannot create user with firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

Cannot create user with firebase
Cannot create user with firebase

Please see below sample firebase code

```
state={email:'',password:'',error:''};

//Firebase configuration
    componentWillMount(){        
      firebase.initializeApp({
          apiKey: '',
          authDomain: '',
          databaseURL: '',
          projectId: '',
          storageBucket: '',
          messagingSenderId: ''
      });
    }
    //Button handler to create user
    onPressHandler(){ 
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      this.state.email,this.state.password)
        .then(() => this.setState({error:'Created'}))
        .catch(() => {this.setState({error: 'Authentication Failed'})}); 
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: The first thing to figuring out what's going wrong is to check the error message you get: `.catch((e) => {console.error(e); this.setState({error: 'Authentication Failed'})});`

Answer (score 0):

In your app.component file

```
import firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");    
ngOnInit(): void {
        firebase.init({
          persist: true,
          storageBucket: 'gs://*********.******.com/',
          onAuthStateChanged: (data: any) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
            if (data.loggedIn) {
              BackendService.token = data.user.uid;
            }
            else {
              BackendService.token = "";
            }
          }
        }).then(
          function (instance) {
            console.log("firebase.init done");
          },
          function (error) {
            console.log("firebase.init error: " + error);
          }
          );
```

In service file

```
import firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");
register(user: User) {
    return new Observable((observer: any) => {
      firebase.createUser(user).then( (result) => {
        observer.next(JSON.stringify(result));
      }).catch((error) => {
        observer.error(error);
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  apiKey: "someApiKey",
  authDomain: "some.auth.domain",
  databaseURL: "dbUrl",
  projectId: "myProjectId",
  storageBucket: "storage",
  messagingSenderId: "8734652304"
}
const myFirebase = firebase.initializeApp(config);

const insert= () => ({
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`value`)
      .set({
        id: data.id,  
      });

});

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
          <Button onPress={this.insert.bind(this)}>My App</Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```